# Заменить часть url у изображения с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли частично заменить url у изображения `img`? Необходимо чтобы url менялся на заданный и только до определенно слова, в данном случае это -  `newwiki`.

Этот код находит изображения и меняет url, заменяя `/newwiki/` на `http://drug/newwiki`. При этом начальный путь очевидно не меняется и url остается не верным.

```
var img = $('img').first();
    $.each(img.get(0).attributes, function() {
      console.log(img);
      if (this.name != 'data-base-url') {
        img.attr(this.name, img.attr(this.name).replace(/newwiki/, 'http://drug/newwiki'));
      }
    });
```

Главная сложность, что первая часть url может быть разной, и заранее не известной.

Как можно изменить url в данном случае?

**UPD**

Пример верного и не правильного url:

неверный url `http://crm.mv.portal-new.web-dev.ru/newwiki/s/ru_RU/6217/82a642d727bee456b0a91262638763d5620b1a86.8/_/images/icons/emoticons/smile.png`

верный url `http://drug/newwiki/s/ru_RU/6217/82a642d727bee456b0a91262638763d5620b1a86.8/_/images/icons/emoticons/smile.png`

Comment: Не вполне понятно что вы хотите сделать, но попробую предположить. Попробуйте менять так: replace(/newwiki/, '/drug/newwiki'))

Comment: А вообще - приведите какой-нибудь пример того, каким у вас может быть изначальный урл, и какой вы бы хотели получить из него после замены.

Comment: спасибо большое. у меня работает) осталось только протестировать у тех у кого не работало.

Comment: Марина, тогда я сейчас вынесу свой комментарий в ответ. А вы, когда убедитесь, что всё работает, отметьте этот ответ как решение. Либо если что не так - пишите коммент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте менять так:

```
replace(/newwiki/, '/drug/newwiki'))
```